# Uniform convergence problem of sequences of functions

Tags: real-analysis

I have been trying to solve this problem for hours...
At this point, I believe that there is a mistake in the problem, but I assume that I am in the one who is wrong. May you help me?

***Here is the problem:***

Let $f_n(x)= \frac{nx}{3+nx},\ n\in \mathbb{N},\ \text{and}\ x>0.$

***a) Show that the sequence $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly on $[a, \infty)$ for any $a>0$***

***b) Show that the sequence $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.***

Here is my perspective:

To prove that the sequence converges uniformly I need to find an $N$ that depends only on epsilon. I am using this definition:

[image: Uniform Convergence definition]

I made a graph with some of the functions:

Here is the graph:

[image: Graph of functions]

According to the graph, from $[1, \infty)$, the limit of the $f_n$ is $1$, but when $x$ is close to 0 the limit, from the right, is $0$.

Then I am wondering is the a of the problem $[a, \infty)$ must be greater or equal than 1 instead of greater than 0 to get uniform convergence.

When I calculate absolute value of $f_n(x) - f(x),$ 
I am getting $nx > \frac{3}{\varepsilon} - 3$.

I do not see how to find an N that depends only on epsilon.

May you tell me if my reasoning is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are absolutely correct that the problem is at $x=0.$ However, you're asked to establish uniform convergence on $[a,\infty)$ for $a>0$, so the problem at zero isn't a problem on this interval. Note that for any $a>0,$ $f_n(a)\to 1$ so it's not the case that points close to $x=0$ have $f(x)\to 0$; this only happens at $x=0$ itself. The points closer to zero will go more slowly, though.

As a reflection of this, notice from your plots that convergence to $1$ improves as $x$ gets larger. This actually helps you see that there's uniform convergence.  The $N$ that works for $x=a$ will also work for $x>a.$ Now, you just need to convert this into a rigorous proof.

And then to show that it doesn't converge uniformly on $[0,\infty),$ just use the problem you noticed at $x=0.$ The function that you converge to pointwise isn't continuous, and this always means that the convergence isn't uniform (if each $f_n$ is continuous).

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, I see a problem because I am getting Nx > (3/epsilon) - 3. I do not see how to convert that to an N that depends only on epsilon.

Comment: @Beginner Pick $N$  so $Na > 3/\epsilon-3.$ Then for all $x\ge a$ and $n>N$ you will have $nx>3/\epsilon-3$ and thus $|1-f_n(x)|<\epsilon$

Comment: @Beginner Is the confusion in 'only on epsilon'? It just means that $N$ cannot depend on $x.$ The inequalities must hold for all $x\in [a,\infty).$ $N$ can depend on $a.$

Comment: It seems that does not work. You are showing pointwise convergence, not uniform convergence.

Comment: @Beginner I am showing uniform convergence. $N$ does not depend on $x$.

Comment: @Beginner Yes that will work.

Comment: Now I understand! You are fixing a. Thank you so much for your patience and help!

Answer (score 2):

For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $$f_n:(0,+\infty)\to\mathbb{R},x\mapsto\frac{nx}{3+nx}$$
The sequence $(f_n)$ is pointwise convergent to $L:x\mapsto 1$.

To decide whether the convergence is uniform or not, consider  :

$$\delta_n(x)=\left|L(x)-f_n(x)\right|=1-\frac{nx}{3+nx}=\frac{3}{3+nx}$$

We see that $\delta_n\left(\frac 1n\right)=\frac 34$, hence $$\sup_{x>0}\delta_n(x)\not\to 0$$

and the convergence is not uniform on $(0,+\infty)$.

However, if we fix $a>0$ and consider $x\in[a,+\infty)$ :

$$\delta_n(x)\le\frac{3}{3+na}$$

Hence :

$$\sup_{x\ge a}\delta_n(x)\le\frac{3}{3+na}\to 0$$

which proves that the convergence is uniform on any $[a,+\infty)$, with $a>0$.

Comment: BTW, I would add that there is some inconsistency in the original question since it is mentioned first $f_n(x)=\cdots$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x>0$ and thereafter we are asked to prove the uniform convergence on $\mathbb{R}$. This last question doesn't make sense since $f_n$ is not even **defined** on $\mathbb{R}$ (take $x=-3/n$).

Comment: Thank you for your time! I really appreciate your help!